# New dictionary using LINQ to dictionary

Tags: c#, linq

I have `Dictionary<Position, List<GameObject>>` and I want to create new dictionary `Dictionary<Position, List<Person>>` which collect positions which including at least one person in the `List<GameObject>`.

I tried:

```
Dictionary<Position, List<Person>> persons =
    positions.ToDictionary(
        i => i.Key, 
        i => i.Value.Where(obj => obj is Person))
```

`positions` is the first dictionary.

but it doesn't really work because the position sometimes is null and its not really type of `Person` because you don't convert it. anyway, do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var people = positions.Select(x => new { x.Key, Values = x.Value.OfType<Person>().ToList() })
                      .Where(x => x.Values.Any())
                      .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Values)
```

Comment: the plural of person is people, other than that +1